# Getting dailymotion videos exact same order with Dailymotion itself using API

Tags: get, dailymotion-api

I'm trying to make an aplication using Dailymotion API. I use video search and want to get them ordered like when you search on dailymotion itself but I think I couldn't find proper parameters.

I tried these get requests:

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?search=Masterchef+(UK)+S15E11

https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?search=Masterchef+(UK)+S15E11&sort=recent

https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?search=Masterchef+(UK)+S15E11&sort=relevance
```

When I try to search in dailymotion.com, result:
[Search Masterchef (UK) S15E11](https://www.dailymotion.com/search/Masterchef%20(UK)%20S15E11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible today to get the same search result with our public API.

The website uses our new API engine which is not available publicly yet but we are working on it.